# Request fix(es) that really work(s) to disable automatic updates in Debian 10.9

Tags: debian

My OS is Debian 10.9 and has the kernel version:

```
Linux localhost 5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.24-1~bpo10+1 (2021-03-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Below is a screenshot of the Software Updates:

[image: Debian Software and Updates]

Based on the guide [How To Stop Automatic Updates On Ubuntu Or Debian](https://dev.to/logix2/how-to-stop-automatic-updates-on-ubuntu-or-debian-2nf7), I typed the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

and click **No** to disable automatic downloads of updates.

Moreover, I renamed the file *50unattended-upgrades* to *50unattended-upgrades-bak* that is in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`

Problem: Debian 10.9 still downloads updates for me automatically in the background. Could someone help me with a fix that really works?

Comment: "I renamed the file 50unattended-upgrades to 50unattended-upgrades-bak" ... `50unattended-upgrades-bak` is just as valid a filename for apt configuration as `50unattended-upgrades` itself is. (See (2) in [`man 5 apt.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html#DESCRIPTION))

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the issue only affects users of Gnome desktop environment.

I solved the problem by switching to a non-Gnome desktop environment.